# applying a function of every element of an RDD

Tags: function, apache-spark, rdd

I am working with a spark rdd. I have to apply a function on every element of that rdd. When I call `rdd.map(x=>function(x))`, the code doesn't give desired output but when I do `rdd.collect().foreach(x=>function(x))`, the code works fine. But the problem with `collect()` is that it brings data to memory making it difficult for data of big size. How do I call this function on every element of rdd?

Comment: What do you mean by _"the code doesn't give desired output"_? Does it throw an error? Does it give the wrong result? What?

Comment: Have you called any action after rdd.map(x=>function(x)) ?

Comment: colRDD5.map(x=>println(x)) doesn't give any result while colRDD5.collect().foreach(x=>println(x)) prints every element

Comment: @RaviRanjan That's because transformations are executed lazily, you must do some action to perform transformation - i.e. count, collect

Answer (score 4):

That's because RDDs are immutable and executed lazily.

When you do `rdd.map(x=>function(x))`, you create new RDD with applied transformation. Applied doesn't mean executed - RDD is a lineage of transformations and action, when you type `rdd.map` you are creating new RDD with one additional step in RDD graph. Thats why if you do:

```
val rdd = // here reading
rdd.map (...)
rdd.collect()
```

the result of `collect()` won't be the source data transformed by `map` function. Old RDD is not changed.

This is first mistake in your code.

Secondly, transformation, map in this case, will be executed **when some action will be triggered** (collect, reduce, etc).

Please check:

```
val mapped = rdd.map(x=>function(x))
// collect is an action, so above transformation map will be executed
mapped.collect().foreach (x => println(x)) // collect will trigger `map` also
```

It will print content after transformation. If you do for example `mapped.count()`, the `map()` also will be executed. Before invocation of an action no transformation will be executed, because RDDs are lazy

Comment: but I cannot call collext() becuase of memory issue. Now, the function in this  case returns an updated list after running on every element of the rdd. When I do .map thing, I can't access that list while in the other case it works.

Comment: `map` and other transformations will be executed ONLY when you will trigger action, such as `collect`, `count,`, `reduce`. It is not possible to change values in RDD than doing map, but transformation will be executed lazily when invoking action

Comment: __lazy__, not  __immutable__, don't you think?

Comment: @LostInOverflow What do you mean? You cannot change RDD itself, but there will be new RDDs created. And invocation will be done lazily. Am I wrong?

Comment: You're right, but what you describe is more an effect of lazy evaluation. It would be the same if RDD was mutable.

Comment: @LostInOverflow Ok, I understand. I've updated answer. I saw that OP was invoking action not on mapped RDD, that's why I mention also about immutability. Now I have clarified that there was two errors

Comment: Okay, I got all of this. why I am really stuck is because I cannot call .collect() or .take(n) as the data is large and both these functions stores data into memory. So, how would I invoke .map function without these? My problem is with the memory.

Comment: @RaviRanjan You can run `count`, it sends only partial counts to the driver and is quite fast, compared to collect, take, etc

Answer (score 0):

try rdd.mapPartitions(func). It applies the function which takes Iterable(ex:list) on each partition. Technically the elements in each partition you can iterate the list and apply a desired function on each element.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your `function(x)` is actually a `println(x)`. The reason why you are not seeing anything printed is because the function is executed on your worker nodes, so it prints to stdout on your worker nodes and *not* on your driver.